# Multimouse functionality in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, xna, adobe, multiple-mice

I am basically looking for a way to use multiple mouse plugged into one device so that multiple pointers can be seen and operate. This is for e-learning purposes, the goal is to have multiple students play an educational game in a classroom that has only got one PC but upto 10 or more mouse connected to a PC.

I did something similar a couple years ago in microsoft XNA framework. Currently I am developing applications and games in Adobe Flash AS3 and would like to find out if there is anyway that we can have multiple mouse functionality in a flash application?

Any sort of help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the web, this is probably impossible. If your flash project run on Adobe Air, you can add native code to handle this kind of functionality or you can use a local socket server to send information over socket to your swf or air application.

[Example for native extension](http://www.flexjunk.com/2011/11/30/developing-an-air-native-extension-for-osx-and-windows-in-c/)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you share some code snippets may be, that will explain your point in more detail. Or may be share a link where similar functionality has been implemented for as3